# HTML POST parameters are submitting as a solid block without ampersands to separate the data

Tags: html, post, parameters, submit

I'm having troubles with getting my HTML to add ampersand separators on a POST values. Here is the relevant html:

```html
<form action="/index.php" enctype="text/plain" method="post">
 <div class="rulebody">
  <p><span class="action" style="font-size:10px;">Action</span></p>
  <p><span class="proto" style="font-size:10px;">Protocol</span></p>
  <p><span class="srcnetwork" style="font-size:10px;">Source Network</span></p>
  <p><span class="srcport" style="font-size:10px;">Source Port/Range</span></p>
  <p><span class="action" style="font-size:10px;">Action</span></p>
  <img class="arrow" src="http://imageprocessor.websimages.com/width/210/crop/0,0,210x210/www.chris-davis.org/arrow.png" style="width:30px;height:35px;" />
  <p><span class="dstnetwork" style="font-size:10px;">Destination Network</span></p>
  <p><span class="dstport" style="font-size:10px;">Destination Port</span></p>
  <p><span class="sid" style="font-size:10px;">SID</span></p>
  <p><span class="rev" style="font-size:10px;">Rev</span></p>
  <p><select class="actionForm" name="action"><option value="alert">alert</option><option value="log">log</option><option value="pass">pass</option><option value="activate">activate</option><option value="dynamic">dynamic</option><option value="drop">drop</option><option value="reject">reject</option><option value="sdrop">sdrop</option></select></p><p><select class="protoForm" name="Protocol"><option value="tcp">tcp</option><option value="icmp">icmp</option><option value="udp">udp</option><option value="ip">ip</option></select></p><p><input class="srcnetworkForm" name="srcnetwork" type="text" placeholder="$HOME_NET" required/><span style="text-align: center;"></p><input class="srcportForm" maxlength="11" name="srcport" size="10" type="text" placeholder="any" required/></span><input class="dstnetworkForm" name="dstnetwork" type="text" placeholder="$SNORPY_NET" required/></p><span style="text-align: center;"><p><input class="dstportForm" maxlength="11" name="dstport" size="10" type="text" placeholder="$HTTP_PORTS" required/></p></span><p><input class="sidForm" maxlength="7" name="sid" size="7" type="text" placeholder="1000001" required/></p><p><input class="revForm" maxlength="3" name="rev" size="7" type="text" placeholder="1" /></p>
  <p><span class="msg" style="font-size: 10px;">Message Text</span></p>
  <p><span class="classType" style="font-size: 10px;">Class-Type</span></p>
  <p><span class="priority" style="font-size: 10px;">Priority</span></p>
  <p><span class="gid" style="font-size: 10px;">GID</span></p>
  <p><input class="msgForm" name="msg" size="79" type="text" placeholder="Snorpy.com is the SHIZ!!!" required/></p><p><input class="classTypeForm" name="classtype" size="20" type="text" placeholder="ROOTACCESS" required/></p><p><input class="priorityForm" maxlength="1" name="priority" size="5" type="text" placeholder="1" required/></p><p><input class="gidForm" maxlength="10" name="gid" size="6" type="text" /></p>
<input class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
 </div>
</form>
```

So i used burpsuite and firefox tamper adata to view the data as I was inputting the POST but all the post paramters get lumped together as:

```
alert=alertProtocol=tcpsrcnetwork=asdfsrcport=asdfdstnetwork=asdfdstport=asdfsid=asdfrev=asdmsg=asdfclasstype=asdfpriority=agid=asdfttlevaluator=ttl=ipprotoevaluator=ipprotofield=httpmethodForm=httpmethodForm=tcpdirectionForm=tcpstateForm=udpdirectionForm=datasizeEval=datasize=reftype=referencetext=thresholdtype=trackby=count=seconds=content1=content1offest=content1depth=content2=content2offset=content2depth=pcre1=pcre2=outPutRule=
```

Whats wrong with my html that it's lumping them together without an ampersand separator?

Answer (score 0):

Ok lol. I figured it out. Basically, the problem is in the:

```html
<form action="/index.php" enctype="text/plain" method="post">
```

I just had to take out enctype="text/plain" and it worked.